# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI while redirect

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, redirect, custom-error-pages

I have registered following viewResolvewer:

```
     <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and wrote following controller method:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String redirectToErrorPage(){
        return "redirect:/errorPage";
    }
```

When following method executes I see following log:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/errorPage] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

page with name `errorPage.jsp` locates under the page folder:
[image]

Please explain what do I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redirecting to the the URL "/errorPage", but there is no request mapping for `/errorPage`. You can add a controller with that request mapping e.g.:

```
@Controller
public class ErrorPageController {

    @RequestMapping("/errorPage")
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String showErrorPage(){
        return "errorPage";
    }
}
```

Or instead of redirecting, you can just show the error page from your exception handler.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public String handleException(Exception e){
    return "errorPage";
}
```

Comment: I can redirect to controller method only?